# Assigning function contents to a variable for text processing

Tags: r, data-mining

I would like to assign a function's contents as text to a variable, so that I can look for various patterns in it.  (Actually, I'd like to assign *every* function's contents to look for how often each function is called from other functions, but that's easy to do once I can do it for one function).

At first glance, this seemed easy.  That's why typing a function name in the console does, which means that `print.function` should show me how to do it:

```
> print.function
function (x, useSource = TRUE, ...) 
.Internal(print.function(x, useSource, ...))
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Fail.  So what if I just assigned the function contents to a variable and coerced them to character?

```
fxn_names <- apropos(".+")
fxns <- lapply(fxn_names,get)
as.character(fxns[[1]])

Error in as.character(fxns[[1]]) : 
  cannot coerce type 'builtin' to vector of type 'character'
```

Is there a trick here?  Perhaps an .Internal function that I don't know about?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`deparse`?

```
> deparse(mean)
[1] "function (x, ...) "  "UseMethod(\"mean\")"
> deparse(`+`)
[1] ".Primitive(\"+\")"
```

and as for getting all function as text, some tricks is necessary:

```
fxn_names <- apropos(".+")
fxns<-lapply(fxn_names, 
  function(f) eval(parse(text=paste("deparse(`", f, "`)", sep=""))))
```

**UPDATED**

here is more simple solution (thanks to @gsk3)

```
fxn_names <- apropos(".+")
fxns <- lapply(fxn_names, function(x)deparse(get(x)))
```

Comment: `deparse` of course!  Thanks.  Why all the machinery to extract the text with lapply?  `fxns.text <- lapply(fxns,deparse)` works fine for me....

Comment: really? that sounds nice! what is `fxns`? could you please put your complete code using `deparse`?

Comment: `fxns` is as defined in my original question (`fxns <- lapply(fxn_names,get)`).  Therefore the line which used `deparse` in my comment was the complete code addition.

Comment: Nice.  `get` is my favorite function of the week :-)